# Как сделать выбор из базы данных по строкам с одинаковым вводом?

Tags: c#, winforms

есть два элемента Chart. как сделать чтобы в одном отображался график по типу - Доход, во втором по типу - Расход с выборкой из базы данных или dtg. также при добавлении того или иного типа он соответсвующим образом отображался в чарте. сейчас выводит полностью всю таблицу в чарт. хочу разделить. 
ИЛИ может подскажите где можно почитать об этом?

```
accountingTableAdapter.Fill(база_данныхDataSet.Accounting);

            chart1.Series["Series1"].XValueMember = (база_данныхDataSet.Tables[0].Columns[1]).ToString();

            chart1.Series["Series1"].YValueMembers = (база_данныхDataSet.Tables[0].Columns[4]).ToString();

            chart1.DataBind();
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Можете использовать выборку в список, а далее загружать со списка в chart.

Comment: а как это? можете подсказать. или где изучить данный вопрос более детально?

Comment: я правильно понял через SELECT * FROM?

Comment: Можно использовать отдельно выборку новым запросом, но если вы уже подгружаете эти все данные, то нет смысла делать дополнительные запросы, достаточно выбрать из таблицы. Один из примеров того, как можно сделать привел в ответе.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Я бы предложил сделать две выборки income и expenses.
В качестве примера приведу следующий псевдокод:

```
        List<ChartView> income = new List<ChartView>();
        List<ChartView> expenses = new List<ChartView>();

        var dataTable = dataSet.Tables[0];
        foreach (DataRow row in dataTable.Rows)
        {
            if (row[4].ToString() == "доход")
                income.Add(new ChartView { Amount = (decimal)row[4], Category = row[1].ToString() });
            else
                expenses.Add(new ChartView { Amount = (decimal)row[4], Category = row[1].ToString() });
        }
```

Созданные списки можно привязать к нужному Chart компоненту.
В качестве модели можно использовать созданную модель:

```
        class ChartView
        {
            public decimal Amount { get; set; }
            public string Category { get; set; }
        }
```

Либо же анонимный тип.

Comment: спасибо большое. сейчас попробую.